# Как авторизоваться через php curl

Tags: php, curl

Сразу при входе на сайт появляется такое окошко для авторизации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом передавать данные для авторизации?

Я пытался сделать так:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);       
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "логин" . ":" . "пароль");       
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://серве");       
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Но ответ получаю: `Access denied.`

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Получилось вот так:

```
function reinit($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'login:password');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте без передачи логина и пароля в `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, т.е. в `CURLOPT_URL` внести запрос:

```
http://login:password@ip_address/дальше_ссылка_на_нужный_вам_файл_или_сервис
```

Comment: пробовал. тоже самое - Access denied.

Comment: добавьте CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Comment: а что в этом параметре передавать?

Comment: Какой тип данных вы в дальнейшем хотите получить из этого ресурса?

Comment: нужно просто инициировать переход на эту страницу

Comment: попрбуйте добавить `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36');`

Comment: также, посмотрите через консоль, какие куки есть, в консоли это `document.cookie()`

Comment: ничего в консоли нет. CURLOPT_USERAGENT тоже не помог

Comment: `$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:password")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);` попробуй так

Comment: у меня как выше написал, получилось, на локальном сервере протестил.

Comment: не выходит. ответ: *HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized Server: webserver/1.0 Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 18:14:45 GMT WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm="MD5"*